# close wikitudePlugin after IR in android cordova app

Tags: javascript, cordova, wikitude

I'm trying to learn how wikitude works. To do that I'm trying to **modify wikitude examples**.

[wikitude examples on github](https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-phonegap-samples/tree/master/SampleAppResources)

my directory organization is the same that you can look in the link, my edits were concentrated in the subfolder [1_ImageRecognition_2_MultipleTargets](https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-phonegap-samples/tree/master/SampleAppResources/world/1_ImageRecognition_2_MultipleTargets) (precisely in the imagerecognition.js)

I was able to redirect to a new page after recognizing the image 
(with `onEnterFieldOfVision()`) but the new page is opened without closing the wikitude plugin. 
the results is that i see like background what is captured by the camera.

I have done many different tests, but none work for me.

please if you are able to show me exactly where I need to place `wikitudePlugin.close ()`, and if I have to define other functions (and possibly where they need to be defined).

I checked the documentation but have not found much information about it. If there are also examples would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

in imagerecognition.js i've:

```
var pageTwo = new AR.Trackable2DObject(this.tracker, "pageTwo", {
            onEnterFieldOfVision: function() {
                alert(" 1 ");
                document.location = "architectsdk://close";
                alert(" 2 ");
                window.location.assign("1to10/pageTwo.html");
                alert(" 3 ");
            }
        });
```

in index.js i've:

```
onUrlInvoke: function (url) {
        alert(" 4 ");
        if (url.indexOf('close') > -1) {
            alert(" 5 ");
            app.wikitudePlugin.close();
            } else {
           alert(" 6 ");
        }
    alert(" 7 ");
}
```

alert 1, 2 and 3 are displayed. 
alert 4, 5, 6 and 7 no.

can you help me to find the error please?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the other page from your PhoneGap application by intercepting an URL in the format "architectsdk://", and setting a callback through the function setOnUrlInvokeCallback (see WikitudePlugin.js, lines 142-151 in the current version)

Comment: i've tried and tried (also with onUrlInvokeCallback)  but it not work. 
in the update i've included my code. Can you explain what i'm doing wrong?